# Get Mode Value With GroupBy

Tags: sql

I have some data like this

```
(AID,Answer)
(1,A)
(1,A)
(1,A)
(1,B)
(1,B)
(1,C)

(2,C)
(2,C)
(2,C)
(2,B)
(2,B)
(3,A)
```

I want to group by AID and take the most frequency of Answer in each group.

The result：

```
(1,A)

(2,C)
```

Use SQL implement.

Comment: Unfortunately, you input lacks in quality regarding its **form**. Such input is very likely to be downvoted and closed. Thus: please use the [edit] link to improve your question. Also note that  *preview* window (together with the help explaining formatting) to improve the quality of your posting. Please note: it is an absolute no-go to use screen shots for code/error messages. Everything that is text should be represented as (formatted/indented) text! Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about and COUNT, and GROUP BY in SQL and apply knowledge to solve this issue. Let us know if you face any issue in that.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to find the answer in the docs? Have you read about GroupBy? This site is for asking questions about actual programming issues, not to ask other people to do the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode is the most common value.  The simplest way uses aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select aid, answer
from (select aid, answer, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by aid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by aid, answer
     ) aa
where seqnum = 1;
```